# JAVA: Bubble sorting ArrayList in jTable

Tags: java, arraylist, jtable, bubble-sort

I am making a jTable of different activities. This table has a column : "Time". I want to sort jTable using Bubble Sort based on this column.

For example: now I have a table where activity "CALL" is 4 hours/week, activity "OMG: is 7 hours/week and activity "ALLO" is 5 hours/week. I want to sort this table so that , first row will be CALL (4 h/w), then second will be ALLO (5 h/w), and third will be OMG (7 h/w).

How would I do that with Bubble Sort?

Look at this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UObeW.png

I already retrieved values from the column "Time" into ArrayList:

```
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 0;i<jTable1.getModel().getRowCount();i++)
        {
        list.add(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i,3)); 
        }
```

Comment: You do know that [`JTable` has inbuilt sorting support](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)?

Comment: I know, but this is an assignment. So, I have to sort it using bubble sort.

Comment: *"How would I do that with Bubble Sort?"* - Start by using POJOs, which encapsulate all the properties, you want to keep this stuff together. There are plenty of [bubble sort](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+bubble+sort&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) examples floating around, you should try adopting one or more to your needs

Comment: I know how to do bubble sort. The problem is I don't know how to implement it tot he table: specifically, how to swap the rows.

Comment: That would depend on the `TableModel`, in which case you have a few possible options - 1. Rebuild the `TableModel` from scratch; 2. Use a predefined `TableModel` which supports moving or swapping the rows; 3. Write your own `TableModel` to provide that support